# Can you create a summary table of list data?

Tags: list

I want to display a summary of values from multiple lists in one table. Each list will have the same subset of Yes/No columns. The summary table will have row for each list and a column for each Y/N column. The values will be the total for each column for each list. There will be a summary row at the bottom.

Is this possible to do out of the box, SPD or something like Excel services? If so, what tools would I use to do this? Right now, I can only see this being done with a little bit of custom dev.

Example of the desired output:

```
List      Col 1     Col 2     Col 3    
List 01   1         8         5         
List 02   4         3         1         
List 03   2         2         3         
Total     7         13        9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the DataFormWebPart, related data sources and custom XSLT. Make sure you JOIN the data sources rather than MERGE them.

In order to build the table you want to build above the XSLT should then be fairly simple - you just need to build the table, using standard HTML and then apply a template to the dataset coming back from each data source which will execute the count you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this [with excel by syncing each list](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/export-a-sharepoint-list-to-a-spreadsheet-HA001119639.aspx) to its own sheet. You can then build a new sheet to pull all the data together. When the data changes you can do a refresh in excel and get the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

If all the lists are in a single site collection then you could use a CQWP with some custom XSLT.

If the lists are in different site collections then you could use a search web part and customise the XSLT.